# Office 365 / Exchange API for windows phone 8/8.1 development project

Tags: windows-phone-8, exchange-server, office365, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone development project (wp8/wp8.1) and need to grab the user's Exchange/Office 365 calendar information. My quick research found the EWS API and Office 365 API preview cannot be used in Windows Phone projects.

Does anyone know any approach/API that I can use to make the oAuth authentication and data retrieving code easier?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any approach?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can either use the calendar object directly which can read info from the phone calendars : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286421(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286421%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) this works, but you don't have any access to attachments for example and there's few others limitations.

Or if you target 8.1 : http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/16/calling-office365-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-1-app/

Or you can use the Exchange Web Services in SOAP or POX like you would do if developing for another platform. I can't post the link, but the reference is on the msdn.

Good luck with exchange development, it's quite a nightmare :)